# Tabula (And PDFPlumber) unable to extract accurately Thai characters from text-based PDF

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py, thai, pdfplumber

i used tabula to extract Thai characters from a pdf. It is a text based form with following text.
XXXX

After running below code:

```
import tabula 
import pandas as pd

pdlist = tabula.read_pdf(r'subscription.PDF',panda_options{'header':None},pages="all", stream=True, encoding='UTF-8')
result_df=pd.concat(pdlist)
print(result_df)
```

I saw from the Print output (and excel export) that some characters are consistently wrong. For example, these few highlighted characters are missing some parts compared to the PDF original.

**PDF ORIGINAL TEXT**
[image: PDF]

**print(result_df)**
[image: Python]

**Excel Export**
[image: Excel Export]

I tested using pdfplumber and faced same issue but for other characters.
Anyone with experience in Thai (or asian) language is able to help in this? Is this something which I need to accept, or is there some tuning or code to add to improve ?